# HTML - Magento Add multiple products in cart

Tags: javascript, html, magento

i need to add 2 or more products in the same to the cart in magento.

```
<div class="actions-primary"> 
    <form data-role="tocart-form" data-product-sku="CODE12345" action="https://blahblah.com/checkout/cart/add/product/12345" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="product" value="12345">
<input type="hidden" name="uenc" value="gfdskjhgd">
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="hfgghfg"/> 
<button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action tocart primary">
<i class="icon-cart icon-span mr-3"></i> 
<span>Add to Cart</span>
</button>
</form>
</div>
</div> 
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
            {
                "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
                    "catalogAddToCart": {
                        "product_sku": "CODE12345"
                    }
                }
            }
</script>
    </div>
```

how can i add in the same time more products in the cart?

thanks in advance

**I have no access to php**